# Multiply Rows With Column in JavaScript using loops

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, rows

I want to multiply rows with columns inside HTML table each td contains input type elements and each is dynamic means they can be created more at runtime but the process of multiplication will remain the same.
[Click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmUtl.jpg)

below is my code

```
var inputs = $(".volo");
var id = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < r.length; j++) {
    if (i < r.length) {
      alert(parseFloat($(inputs[i]).val()) + "*" + r[j]);
      j = 0;
    } else {
      j = j + 1;
      alert(parseFloat($(inputs[i]).val()) + "*" + r[j]);
    }
    break;
  }
}
```

above code works fine when a number of rows and columns are 2 .inputs contains values coming from one type of tds and r array contains values coming from different tds.length of inputs array will always be greater than r array.

Comment: Do you have a question or a problem?

Comment: problem in multiplication please check the image attach how i want to multiply.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmUtl.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The first loop should loop the column while the second loop should be the row loop, assume you need to read the input you can do this with jquery ,let x be row while y be column

```
 $(`#volX${x}Y${y}` ).val()
```

Your Add Chemical Vol button must be able to create specific mapping of id="volX**num**Y**num**" input.

play around with that it might help you solve your problem

Comment: The link above seems to be broken for me

Comment: i have hosted code here jobinpapers.com/devi/.  when i click on calculate button it multiply chem vol1 ,chem vol2 dynically created with clean rate

Comment: if we have 3 rows i will execute from i=0 to i<arrayname.length while j has number of rows equal to number of rows created through add chemical volume button.but column will be 1 always

Comment: sorry to see nobody on stackoverflow can answer my question